# Retrieving Unknown Column Names from DataFrame.apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How I can retrieve column names from a call to DataFrame `apply` without knowing them in advance?

What I'm trying to do is apply a mapping from column names to functions to arbitrary DataFrames. Those functions might return multiple columns. I would like to end up with a DataFrame that contains the original columns as well as the new ones, the amount and names of which I don't know at build-time.

Other solutions here are Series-based. I'd like to do the whole frame at once, if possible.

What am I missing here? Are the columns coming back from `apply` lost in destructuring unless I know their names? It looks like `assign` might be useful, but will likely require a lot of boilerplate.

```py
import pandas as pd

def fxn(col):
    return pd.Series(col * 2, name=col.name+'2')

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0, 10), 'B': range(10, 0, -1)})
print(df)

# [Edit:]
#    A   B
# 0  0  10
# 1  1   9
# 2  2   8
# 3  3   7
# 4  4   6
# 5  5   5
# 6  6   4
# 7  7   3
# 8  8   2
# 9  9   1

df = df.apply(fxn)
print(df)

# [Edit:]
# Observed: columns changed in-place.
#     A   B
# 0   0  20
# 1   2  18
# 2   4  16
# 3   6  14
# 4   8  12
# 5  10  10
# 6  12   8
# 7  14   6
# 8  16   4
# 9  18   2

df[['A2', 'B2']] = df.apply(fxn)
print(df)

# [Edit: I am doubling column values, so missing something, but the question about the column counts stands.]
# Expected: new columns added. How can I do this at runtime without knowing column names?
#     A   B  A2  B2
# 0   0  40   0  80
# 1   4  36   8  72
# 2   8  32  16  64
# 3  12  28  24  56
# 4  16  24  32  48
# 5  20  20  40  40
# 6  24  16  48  32
# 7  28  12  56  24
# 8  32   8  64  16
# 9  36   4  72   8
```

Comment: Not that you do simple operation and using apply, this is really not recommended because tou can easily change it to vectorized way, whichi will be much much faster..

Comment: Completely agree @adirabargil -- the real function is very complex, this is just a toy example :)

Comment: If performance is important to you try to convert that to a vectorized way too :) you can allways get help here..

Comment: Don't update the question with an answer. If you want to add an alternative solution post it in the answer space below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*Answer on the behalf of OP:*</sub>

This code does what I wanted:

```
import pandas as pd

# Simulated business logic: for an input row, return a number of columns
# related to the input, and generate names for them, such that we don't
# know the shape of the output or the names of its columns before the call.
def fxn(row):
    length = row[0]
    indicies = [row.index[0] + str(i) for i in range(0, length)]
    series = pd.Series([i for i in range(0, length)], index=indicies)
    return series

# Sample data: 0 to 18, inclusive, counting by 2.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0, 20, 2)), columns=['A'])

# Randomize the rows to simulate different input shapes.
df1 = df1.sample(frac=1)

# Apply fxn to rows to get new columns (with expand). Concat to keep inputs.
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1.apply(fxn, axis=1, result_type='expand')], axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `concat` the result of your function with the original `df`.

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [8]: x = df.apply(fxn) # Apply function on df and store result separately
In [10]: df = pd.concat([df, x], axis=1) # Concat with original df to get all columns
```

#### Rename duplicate column names by adding suffixes:

```
In [82]: from collections import Counter

In [38]: mylist = df.columns.tolist()
In [41]: d = {a:list(range(1, b+1)) if b>1 else '' for a,b in Counter(mylist).items()}

In [62]: df.columns = [i+str(d[i].pop(0)) if len(d[i]) else i for i in mylist]

In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
   A1  B1  A2  B2
0   0  10   0  20
1   1   9   2  18
2   2   8   4  16
3   3   7   6  14
4   4   6   8  12
5   5   5  10  10
6   6   4  12   8
7   7   3  14   6
8   8   2  16   4
9   9   1  18   2
```

Comment: This will work for the column, not row, axis? Giving it a shot...

Comment: Ahh, I see -- it works, however I am missing the column names: A, B, A2, B2.

Comment: You want the new column names like `A, B, A2, B2`?

Comment: Yes, working on that part now -- this is very close.

Comment: Just bedore concat add `x.columns = [str(col) + '2' for col in list(x.columns)]`

Comment: @AlexFlanagan I've updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I should be more clear: the '2' is an example, it could be an arbitrary string. I won't know what the columns are called coming back from apply.

Comment: @AlexFlanagan I've edited answer further to rename columns. Have a look.

Comment: Very good idea to use `pd.concat` and manage duplicated column names! It should definitely be the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can assign directly with:

```
df[df.columns + '2'] = df.apply(fxn)
```

Outut:

```
   A   B  A2  B2
0  0  10   0  20
1  1   9   2  18
2  2   8   4  16
3  3   7   6  14
4  4   6   8  12
5  5   5  10  10
6  6   4  12   8
7  7   3  14   6
8  8   2  16   4
9  9   1  18   2
```

---

Alternatively, you can leverage the @MayankPorwal answer by using `.add_suffix('2')` to the output from your apply function:

```
pd.concat([df, df.apply(fxn).add_suffix('2')], axis=1)
```

which will return the same output.

---

In your function, `name=col.name+'2'` is doing nothing (it's basically returning just `col * 2`). That's because `apply` returns the values back to the original column.

Anyways, it's possible to take the MayankPorwal approach: `pd.concat` + managing duplicated columns (make them unique). Another possible way to do that:

```py
# Use pd.concat as mentioned in the first answer from Mayank Porwal
df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(fxn)], axis=1)

# Rename duplicated columns
suffix = (pd.Series(df.columns).groupby(df.columns).cumcount()+1).astype(str)
df.columns = df.columns + suffix.rename('1', '')
```

which returns the same output, and additionally manage further duplicated columns.

Comment: add_suffix is interesting -- I won't know what the column names are coming back from apply, but maybe I can make that work.

Comment: Nice use of  `add_suffix`. +1.

Comment: Ahh, I also won't necessarily know the number of columns coming back. So 'A' could map to 'A2', 'A3', and 'A4'.

Comment: @AlexFlanagan, you might consider providing us an example of such function returning multiple columns. But as it is, returning a named `Series` doesn't work at all. We just get the values (that's how `apply` works). You may change your function (if it's possible) to apply it per column in a for loop, which is basically what `apply` does.

Comment: Anyways, I updated my answer as well to manage duplicated columns. The idea, though, is originally from @MayankPorwal, so if it works for you, his answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva I updated the question with code that does what I wanted, based on answer here -- thank you!